# How to know in firemonkey that focus is inside a control?

Tags: delphi, focus, firemonkey

I'm developing TPanel with new style trigger "IsFocusInside". It will trigger when one control of childs inside panel has focused and when we have no focus at all of them. How do I know when a control inside is focused and when none of them focused? I do not know what type and how many controls will be inside my Panel. Tnx.

Comment: by _trigger_ you meant _event_?

Comment: No, IsXXXX properties are ones which automatically trigger events and animations within the style when they are changed. (Note if you're coding one yourself you need to manually trigger then within your component).

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the controls (any their children) and patch into the OnEnter (gets focus) and OnExit (loses focus) events.